# How do you add a settings page to another menu?

Tags: plugins, admin-menu, options, sub-menu

I created a settings page that's being displayed in the options menu like this:

```
add_options_page(
    'ATB Event Options',
    'ATB Event Options',
    'manage_options',
    'atb-event-options',
    'atb_event_options_display'
);
```

Instead, I'd like to display it as a menu item under another parent menu with the slug 'mvc_events':

```
add_submenu_page(
    'mvc_events',
    'ATB Event Options',
    'ATB Event Options',
    'manage_options',
    'atb-event-options',
    'atb_event_options_display'
);
```

While that does add "ATB Event Options" to my mvc_events menu, it overwrites the first menu item I had there, and the link doesn't even work. The link is generated as blah.dev/wp-admin/atb-event-options.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create the top-level menu page, and then the sub-menu after that.

Here's an example:

```
function my_menu() {
  add_menu_page ( 
    'MVC Events',      // $page_title
    'MVC Events',      // $menu_title
    'manage_options',  // $capability
    'mvc-events',      // $menu_slug
    'mvc-options'      // $function
    );
  add_submenu_page (
    'mvc-events',         // $parent_slug
    'ATB Event Options',  // $page_title
    'ATB Event Options',  // $menu_title
    'manage_options',     // $capability
    'atb-event-options',  // $menu_slug
    'atb-options'         // $function
    );
  }
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_menu' );
```

Here's [the pertinent WP codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) file, and one particularly [on sub-menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page).

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using WP-MVC which generates menus by default and I can't override it. So I'm guessing I'm screwed.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, I'd suggest contacting Tom Benner, the developer, directly then.  His contact is [available online](https://github.com/tombenner).